# Missing signal type parameter in Add-AzMetricAlertRule PowerShell command

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to add a new metric alert rule through powershell, but some parameters in the command are missing.  For example, How to pass the parameters if I want to configure the signal types ?

Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name
                      -Location
                      -ResourceGroup
                      -Operator
                      -TargetResourceId
                      -MetricName 
                      -TimeAggregationOperator Total
                      -WindowSize 
                      -Description 
                      -Action

[Configure Signal types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fTCG.png)

Comment: are you trying to set up an alert for azure vm?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I am. But I want a standard code that will work for all type of resources.

Comment: @CharlesXu , I want to attach existing action groups(two) to that alert rule.  How should I specify them in the Action parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the signal types in the parameter `-MetricName` like this:

```
Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name name -Location yourLocation -ResourceGroupName yourGroup -Operator GreaterThan -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -Threshold 0.1 -WindowSize 00:05:00 -TargetResourceId yourVMResourceId -TimeAggregationOperator Total
```

But it's the classic alert rule. I do not find the PowerShell command to create the new alert rules. But you can create the new alert rules in the portal or through [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-alert-create). See the [difference between Old and New alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-classic.overview).